# Access operator / accessor in C# class

Tags: c#, class

If I create a class in C# example a Custom Matrix4 class is it possible to write the class in a way that allow me to access it without having to access explicitly the member variable.

**Example of a simple Matrix4 class:**

```
class Matrix4
{
    private double[,] _m = new double[4, 4] { { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
    public double[,] m
    {
        get { return (_m); }
        set { _m = value; }
    }
}
```

and to access the actual 2D array aka the matrix I would have to write **m4.m[1, 1]** is it possible to have it where you don't have to write the **.m**  so it would just be **m4[1, 1]**, it not super importation but it would be nice and it possible in C++ so thought it might be possible in C# as well but haven't been able to find anything about it.

**Current how to access it:**

```
Matrix4 m4 = new Matrix4();
Debug.Log(m4.m[1, 1]);
```

**How I would like it to be:**

```
Matrix4 m4 = new Matrix4();
Debug.Log(m4[1, 1]);
```

Comment: Yes, it's called an indexer. You can read about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of Indexers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609594/what-is-the-use-of-indexers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Array indexer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707951/how-to-implement-array-indexer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its called indexer in C# thanks to @[itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86) comment pointing that out.

**Here is how to do it with the matrix example:**

```
 class Matrix4
    {
        private double[,] _m = new double[4, 4] { { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
        public double this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return (_m[x, y]); }
            set { _m[x, y] = value; }
        }
    }
```

**and to access it:**

```
Matrix4 m4 = new Matrix4();
Debug.Log(m4[1, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an indexer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

```
class Matrix4
{
    private double[,] _m = new double[4, 4] { { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
    public double this[int i,int j]
    {
        get { return (_m[i,j]); }
        set { _m[i,j] = value; }
    }
}
var m4 = new Matrix4();
// m4[1,1] == 1
```